# Allocation of pthread stack in glibc

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, pthreads, posix

POSIX threads usually share the address space. But each thread has its own stack. How is that stack allocated. I already looked into the allocate_stack function in the glibc but I didn't understand it. 
Is it theoretically possible to access the stack of another pthread because the address space is shared?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In most pthread implementations, you *could* access the stack of another thread without triggering some sort of fault via hardware memory management. A common mistake is to program threads as if they are potentially 'adversarial', like processes. This is wrong. It's why calls like `pthread_kill` (and even `pthread_cancel`) are usually a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's possible.
For example:

```
#include        <signal.h>
#include        <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void * f(void * arg)
{
    int * p = (int*)arg;
    *p = 10;
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t t;
    int var = 5;
    pthread_create(&t, NULL,f,&var);
    pthread_join(t,NULL);
    printf("var=%d\n",var);
    return (0);
}
```

The output will be "var=10", not 5